# Lillifors test in Python (wrong p-values)

Tags: python, statistics

The code beneath, generates 1000 samples, of size 100, from normal distribution with mean =0 and sd=1, and for each sample it saves the p-value of the lillifors test for normality of each sample.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
b=1000
pvalues=[0]*b
for i in range(b): pvalues[i]=sm.stats.lillifors(np.random.normal(0,1,100))[1]
```

Then I take the maximum of all the p-values, which gives a result over 1, which means that there was at least one p-value over 1. How is it possible? Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

```
print(np.max(pvalues))
1.28471963277
```

In R the same procedure doesn't give strange results. Another thing that I noticed, is that Python allows the lillifors test to be performed for sample size lower than 5.

Comment: I also get p-values larger than 1. Might be a bug in the statsmodels? You can write some random distributions to file and then run this test in both R and Python and to see where they disagree

Comment: I did something similar... for x=1,.....,10, I performed lilliefors test both in Python and R. Both R and Python give the same value for D, however the p-values differ, while R gives p-value  about 0.9,  Python gives p-value over 1.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me as p should be <= 1 . Finally confirmation would be to implement the Lillfors test yourself as a) you then have a working test and b) you can submit  a bug report. Sorry not to be of more help